# Calculate cell sizes and draw (with lines in between) them

Tags: java, graphics

I want to draw a grid and draw stuff in the cells (to keep things easy just fill them).
Overall I've got it pretty much working only in some panel sizes the cell is about 1 pixel off of where it should be placed (overlapping the line).
TBH I haven't really done enough calculating to possibly find the answer myself, so my apologies for that, I'm really not too sure how to approach this "bug" either though.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Gui().setVisible(true);
}

public Gui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(new JPanel() {
        public static final int SIZE = 3;
        /** Line thickness ratio to a block */
        public static final float LINE_THICKNESS = 0.1f;

        /** @return the width of a block. */
        protected final int getBlockWidth() {
            return getWidth() / SIZE;
        }

        /** @return the height of a block. */
        protected final int getBlockHeight() {
            return getHeight() / SIZE;
        }

        /**  @return the width of a cell. */
        protected final int getCellWidth() {
            return (int) Math.ceil(getBlockWidth()*(1-LINE_THICKNESS));
        }

        /** @return the height of a cell. */
        protected final int getCellHeight() {
            return (int) Math.ceil(getBlockHeight()*(1-LINE_THICKNESS));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 100));
            int lineWidth = (int) (LINE_THICKNESS * getBlockWidth());
            int lineHeight = (int) (LINE_THICKNESS * getBlockHeight());
            for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {
                g.fillRect(i * getBlockWidth() - lineWidth / 2, 0, lineWidth, getHeight());
                g.fillRect(0, i * getBlockHeight() - lineHeight/2, getWidth(), lineHeight);
            }
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 100));
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    int x = j * getBlockWidth() + lineWidth/2;
                    int y = i * getBlockHeight() + lineHeight/2;
                    Graphics temp = g.create(x, y, getCellWidth(), getCellHeight());
                    drawCell(temp, i, j);
                }
            }
        }

        private void drawCell(Graphics g, int i, int j) {
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getCellWidth(), getCellHeight());
        }
    });
    setLocation(new Point(500, 200));
    setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
}
}
```

If you run it you'll probably see what I mean. I can't think of a good explanation in words. At first I thought I had to add + 1 to x and y since I want to draw next to the line, but this (obviously) just shifts the problem to the other side.

Running this with a SIZE bigger (like 30) gives me another bug that it gives open space to the sides. I know (or assume) this is because I'm using integers and it isn't too big of a deal though. But hints for a better approach (in general) are always welcome.

Comment: Definite +1 for a good SSCCE.org and clear, understandable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you can fix this. I will not give you code, since I believe (based on how you asked your question) you are one of those who like to think and solve problems on their own.

First of all: first draw the background on the whole panel and then draw the lines. There'll be no while lines and the drawing will be slightly faster.

Second way: the order of drawing is important. You can safely draw the background first (even if it overlaps) and then overwrite it with borders.

Third way: do not use ints. Use floats or doubles. All your trouble will go away.

Fourth way: calculate the remainder. You can predict when the lines are drawn and when not, think about it. Predict it and draw appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had your same problem but the solution I implemented is inspired by the sample available from the Java Tutorial for drawing multiline text and draws the text on the cell using the text APIs.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.text.BreakIterator;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class MultilineTableCell 
    implements TableCellRenderer {
    class CellArea extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String text;
        protected int rowIndex;
        protected int columnIndex;
        protected JTable table;
        protected Font font;
        private int paragraphStart,paragraphEnd;
        private LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer;

        public CellArea(String s, JTable tab, int row, int column,boolean isSelected) {
            text = s;
            rowIndex = row;
            columnIndex = column;
            table = tab;
            font = table.getFont();
            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            }
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
            super.paintComponent(gr);
            if ( text != null && !text.isEmpty() ) {
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
                if (lineMeasurer == null) {
                    AttributedCharacterIterator paragraph = new AttributedString(text).getIterator();
                    paragraphStart = paragraph.getBeginIndex();
                    paragraphEnd = paragraph.getEndIndex();
                    FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
                    lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(paragraph,BreakIterator.getWordInstance(), frc);
                }
                float breakWidth = (float)table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).getWidth();
                float drawPosY = 0;
                // Set position to the index of the first character in the paragraph.
                lineMeasurer.setPosition(paragraphStart);
                // Get lines until the entire paragraph has been displayed.
                while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < paragraphEnd) {
                    // Retrieve next layout. A cleverer program would also cache
                    // these layouts until the component is re-sized.
                    TextLayout layout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(breakWidth);
                    // Compute pen x position. If the paragraph is right-to-left we
                    // will align the TextLayouts to the right edge of the panel.
                    // Note: this won't occur for the English text in this sample.
                    // Note: drawPosX is always where the LEFT of the text is placed.
                    float drawPosX = layout.isLeftToRight()
                        ? 0 : breakWidth - layout.getAdvance();
                    // Move y-coordinate by the ascent of the layout.
                    drawPosY += layout.getAscent();
                    // Draw the TextLayout at (drawPosX, drawPosY).
                    layout.draw(g, drawPosX, drawPosY);
                    // Move y-coordinate in preparation for next layout.
                    drawPosY += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
                }
                table.setRowHeight(rowIndex,(int) drawPosY);
            }
        }
    }
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,int column
        )
    {
        CellArea area = new CellArea(value.toString(),table,row,column,isSelected);
        return area;
    }   
}
It resizes row heigth too but it does it well only when this renderer is used for a single column.

And this is the way I used to invoke it for render my table.

final int wordWrapColumnIndex = ...;
myTable = new JTable() {    
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        if (column == wordWrapColumnIndex ) {
            return wordWrapRenderer;
        }
        else {
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        }
    }
};
```